# Letter f in TeX Gyre Pagella Math

Tags: luatex

I'm using LuaLaTeX to compile the following document.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \partial_x f(u),
  \quad
  \partial_j f^j(u),
  \quad
  uf
  \quad
  \partial_x u,
  \quad
  \partial_j u
  \quad
  q_j+q_f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The spacing before the `f` seems to be really weird: The indices of the `\partial` symbol and `f` overlap. Can I increase the spacing in front of `f` in math mode somehow without altering every single appearance of `f`?

Comment: Confirming the same problem for: TeX Gyre Termes Math , TeX Gyre Bonum Math.  Seems ok: TeX Gyre Schola Math, STIX Math and Latin Modern Math.   And the good news for the end:  Asana Math is almost the same font without that problem. Test it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` may not be quite ready for prime time. I suggest you load the `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` packages -- they work just fine under LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools} % optional
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \partial_x f(u),
  \quad
  \partial_j f^j(u),
  \quad
  uf
  \quad
  \partial_x u,
  \quad
  \partial_j u
  \quad
  q_j+q_f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One can patch a font but it also affects the smaller sizes (the subscript) and finding good value is not easy:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}

local patch_pagellamath = function (fontdata)
 if fontdata.psname == "TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular"
 then
 fontdata.characters[119891]["width"]=314380.16 -- 364380.16
 fontdata.characters[119891]["commands"]={
{ 'right', 100000 },{'font',0},{ 'char', 119891 }}
 end
end



luatexbase.add_to_callback
 (
  "luaotfload.patch_font",
  patch_pagellamath,
  "change_pagellamath"
 )
\end{luacode}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
  \partial_x f(u),
  \quad
  \partial_j f^j(u),
  \quad
  uf
  \quad
  \partial_x u,
  \quad
  \partial_j u
  \quad
  q_j+q_f
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution... just a fix and I am not expected to accept it since it seems to be a bug of that fonts.

My suggestion is to use `Asana Math`... it is really so close that I don't think that their creator can recognize them (If are not just one creator). You can see it in my (not recommended) fix too that redefines j in a command for math.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


\def\f{\,f}
\begin{document}


Confirming the same problem for: TeX Gyre Termes Math , 
TeX Gyre Bonum Math. Seems ok: TeX Gyre Schola Math, STIX Math 
and Latin Modern Math. And the good news for the end: Asana Math is
almost the same font without that problem. Test it! 


\setmainfont{Asana-Math}\selectfont $Non$ TeX Gyre Pagella Test f 

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}\selectfont $\phantom{Non}$ TeX Gyre Pagella Test f 

\setmathfont{Asana Math}\selectfont
\begin{equation}
  \partial_x f(u),
  \quad
  \partial_j f^j(u),
  \quad
  uf
  \quad
  \partial_x u,
  \quad
  \partial_j u
  \quad
  q_j+q_f
\end{equation}

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}\selectfont
\begin{equation}
  \partial_x \f(u),
  \quad
  \partial_j \f^j(u),
  \quad
  u\f 
  \quad
  \partial_x u,
  \quad
  \partial_j u
  \quad
  q_j+q_{f}%Here no space needed
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Loading the `unicode-math` package automatically loads the `fontspec` package as well.

Comment: Thanks Mico... But I needed to load it at least twice :P... 3 times works fine :) (Edited)