# Increase the space before letter "f" in math mode (unicode-math)

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

When using the font "TeX Gyre Pagella Math", I would like to add an appropriate space before the letter "f", so that

[image]

becomes

[image]

This question has been asked before, notably [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399505/194994), but the solutions are not very satisfactory by now. I'm particularly interested in [Ulrike Fischer's Lua code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399555/194994) solution, but I'm getting the following error:

```
error:  (vf): invalid DVI command (2)
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Another answer suggested using "Asana Math" instead of "TeX Gyre Pagella Math", but there shall be other problems, for example the space between the letter "f" and the subscript that follows seems to be too large:

[image]

(*This has been solved in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650491/194994)*)

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local patch_pagellamath = function (fontdata)
  if fontdata.psname == "TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular"
  then
  fontdata.characters[119891]["width"]=314380.16 -- 364380.16
  fontdata.characters[119891]["commands"]={
    { 'right', 100000 },{'font',0},{ 'char', 119891 }}
  end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback
  (
    "luaotfload.patch_font",
    patch_pagellamath,
    "change_pagellamath"
  )
\end{luacode}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\( (f) \)

\( f_i f_j \)

\( g f \) \( f g \)

\( \wideoverbar{f} f \)

\( f \wideoverbar{f} \)

Expected:

\( (\,f) \)

\( f_i \, f_j \)

\( g \, f \) \( f g \)

\( \wideoverbar{f} f \)

\( f \, \wideoverbar{f} \)

\end{document}
```

Below is my log file:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)  (format=lualatex 2022.7.7)  10 JUL 2022 12:03
 restricted system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**/var/folders/6d/28f2j4px63sf0czptbdj14pr0000gn/T/lua-patchfont-test.tex
(/var/folders/6d/28f2j4px63sf0czptbdj14pr0000gn/T/lua-patchfont-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-06-15 3.22 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/xujinwen/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-06-15.lua" from kpse-resolved path "/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2022-06-15.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.120
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/xujinwen/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'. L3 programming layer <2022-07-04>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'. (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /Users/xujinwen/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen137
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
Package: luacode 2012/01/23 v1.2a lua-in-tex helpers (mpg)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count191
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable12
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable13
)
\luacode@lines=\toks16
\luacode@table@soft=\catcodetable14
)
Inserting `change_pagellamath' at position 7 in `luaotfload.patch_font'. (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-07-04 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2022-07-01 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count192
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package: unicode-math 2020/01/31 v0.8q Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
Package: unicode-math-luatex 2020/01/31 v0.8q Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2022-06-22 L3 Experimental document command parser
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2022-06-22 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2022/01/15 2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count193
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count194
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count195
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count196
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count197
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count198
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count199
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count266
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen138
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen139
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen140
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2020/11/24 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TS1 on input line 47.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count270
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 236.
\uproot@=\count271
\leftroot@=\count272
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count273
\DOTSCASE@=\count274
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count275
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count276
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count277
\dspbrk@lvl=\count278
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count279
\column@=\count280
\maxfields@=\count281
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty
Package: lualatex-math 2022/01/01 v1.12 Patches for mathematics typesetting with LuaLaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count282
)
Lua module: lualatex-math 2013/08/03 1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting with LuaLaTeX)
\g__um_fam_int=\count283
\g__um_fonts_used_int=\count284
\l__um_primecount_int=\count285
\g__um_primekern_muskip=\muskip17
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'texgyrepagella-math.otf(0)' created for
(fontspec)             font 'texgyrepagella-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script=Math,FontAdjustment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: 


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'texgyrepagella-math.otf(1)' created for
(fontspec)             font 'texgyrepagella-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.7-},{Size=6.45-8.7,Font=texgyrepagella-math.otf,Style=MathScript},{Size=-6.45,Font=texgyrepagella-math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},FontAdjustment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.7->"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;"<6.45-8.7>"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6.45>"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(1)/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(1)/b/n on input line 23.

Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'texgyrepagella-math.otf(2)' created for
(fontspec)             font 'texgyrepagella-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.7-},{Size=6.45-8.7,Font=texgyrepagella-math.otf,Style=MathScript},{Size=-6.45,Font=texgyrepagella-math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},FontAdjustment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             },ScaleAgain=1.0001,FontAdjustment={\fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =7.2pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =4.68999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =4.68999pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =6.65999pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =3.10999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =3.54pt\relax \fontdimen 14\font
(fontspec)             =3.54pt\relax \fontdimen 15\font =2.95999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 16\font =2.31999pt\relax \fontdimen 17\font
(fontspec)             =2.31999pt\relax \fontdimen 18\font =2.31999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 19\font =1.15999pt\relax \fontdimen 22\font
(fontspec)             =2.5pt\relax \fontdimen 20\font =0pt\relax \fontdimen
(fontspec)             21\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.7->s*[1.0001]"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;"<6.45-8.7>s*[1.0001]"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6.45>s*[1.0001]"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: \fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =7.2pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =4.68999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =4.68999pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =6.65999pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =3.10999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =3.54pt\relax \fontdimen 14\font
(fontspec)             =3.54pt\relax \fontdimen 15\font =2.95999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 16\font =2.31999pt\relax \fontdimen 17\font
(fontspec)             =2.31999pt\relax \fontdimen 18\font =2.31999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 19\font =1.15999pt\relax \fontdimen 22\font
(fontspec)             =2.5pt\relax \fontdimen 20\font =0pt\relax \fontdimen
(fontspec)             21\font =0pt\relax 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(2)/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(2)/b/n on input line 23.

Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: texgyrepagella-math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'texgyrepagella-math.otf(3)' created for
(fontspec)             font 'texgyrepagella-math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.7-},{Size=6.45-8.7,Font=texgyrepagella-math.otf,Style=MathScript},{Size=-6.45,Font=texgyrepagella-math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},FontAdjustment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             },ScaleAgain=0.9999,FontAdjustment={\fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =0.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =1.2pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =1.2pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =1.2pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =4.68pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.7->s*[0.9999]"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;"<6.45-8.7>s*[0.9999]"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=0;"<-6.45>s*[0.9999]"[texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: \fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =0.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =1.2pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =1.2pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =1.2pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =4.68pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =0pt\relax 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(3)/m/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(3)/b/n on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.00107pt on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.40077pt on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.50058pt on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.99893pt on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.3992pt on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.4994pt on input line 23.
 (./lua-patchfont-test.aux)
\openout1 = lua-patchfont-test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/texgyrepagella-math.otf(1)/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 24.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no 
warning  (print): bad string pointer
 (U+44383335) in font [texgyrepagella-math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;!
/var/folders/6d/28f2j4px63sf0czptbdj14pr0000gn/T/lua-patchfont-test.tex:48: error:  (vf): invalid DVI command (2)
/var/folders/6d/28f2j4px63sf0czptbdj14pr0000gn/T/lua-patchfont-test.tex:48:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: the code compiles without error for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I attached my log file to the question, could you see from it what is wrong on my side?