# Automatic vertical bar becomes too long for certain letters with Asana-Math

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, asana

Consider the following example:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
% \setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\( \left. g \right| \) \( \left. h \right| \)

\( \scriptstyle \left. g \right| \) \( \scriptstyle \left. h \right| \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the automatic vertical bar is too long for the letter `g` for this font (this also happens for `f`, `j`, `p`, `q` and `y`). Taking `KpMath` as comparison:

[image]

Is there some way to fix this behavior? (Since I'm using LuaLaTeX, it would be nice to have a Lua solution if general solution is not available.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of automatic sizing with `\left.` and `\right`, you can use `\rvert`, perhaps with manual sizing such as `\big\rvert` or `\bigg\rvert`.

You might also have better luck in some cases with TeX Gyre Pagella Math, which like Asana Math is based on Palatino.

Comment: Actually the automatic sizing is part of the restriction command [here in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22255). Also it is actually due to an unsolved question regarding the spacing around letter `f` with the font TeX Gyre Pagella Math that had me switched to Asana Math: see my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650418).

Comment: @Jinwen You could use something like s paired math delimiter from mathtools, where `\restriction{g}` is normal-size, but `\restriction*{g}` auto-sizes and `\restriction[\big]{g}` specifies an exact size.